# How does the Phantom ensure male offspring?

Tags: comics, the-phantom

In the *The Phantom* comic, there is always a son ready to take over duties as The Phantom if the father should fail.

How does The Phantom ensure this? I mean, to always find a woman willing to bear children, then to make sure that he has a son rather than say several daughters.

Is this ever touched on in the comics? Some ancient potion to ensure a male child or something?

Comment: Dunno if this is canonical, but I would presume the production of an heir to the role is something the Phantom is duty-bound to ensure.  With there being plenty of fish in the pond, as they say, this wouldn't be something too difficult to maintain as long as one can find time for it in their busy superhero life.  And, it could be possible that the Phantoms are by some means genetically mutated so that they only produce Y chromosomes.

Comment: @Iszi the current Phantom has a son and a daughter so it doesn't look like that's it.

Comment: @Legion600 Well, that knocks off the latter half of the theory.  But the first part still holds.

Comment: As per my knowledge, there has also been cases of "Lady Phantom" in Lee Falk's series. I remember in a story, our 21st Phantom was reading the anscestral books where the jungle people described that the "immortal" Phantom once (or more) came in the guise of a female. "He" had apparently changed gender. This is probably cause to believe that there may have been a Lady Phantom. Lee Falk wrote so, but AFAIK, no comic strip ever got published depicting a "She" Phantom.

Comment: Old jungle secret.

Answer (score 6):

After reviewing these two sources, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Phantom) and [Comicology](http://www.comicology.in/2009/04/lee-falks-phantom-1-origins-of-ghost.html), I can't find any references as to how The Phantom was able to ensure he had a male heir. I used to read the comic strip fairly regularly growing up, and I don't recall that was ever addressed, just that the oldest male child was always ready to take over when the current Phantom died, or was about to die (nor was I able to find any mention of any of the Phantoms living long enough to retire).

Comment: The current Phantom has been on the job since 1936.  He didn't get married until 1977.  Long time to not have an heir to take over.

Comment: @Legion600 - Plenty of men throughout primate history managed to produce an offspring without being married

Comment: @DVK Yes they have, however the Phantom still in many ways upholds the social mores of his 1936 creation.  When you consider that creator Lee Falk's word is still law in the Phantom universe even though he died in 1999 then the idea of the character having a child out of wedlock is unlikely if not impossible.

Answer (score 1):

First, finding mates. Phantom is supposed to be brave, dashing (OK, going off a movie here - not sure if that part is canon :), very athletic, smart, and not exactly poor. Oh, and he saves damsels in distress, too. Given a highly hypergamic nature of female attraction, he'd not have too much of a trouble of finding a mate there, eh?

Second, "all daughters". Humans have a ~50% (100:105 if I recall correctly) chance of having a male offspring. Unless you are somehow genetically deficient ala inbred European royalty (who still likely have the same odds but the heirs would be more likely to die hemophilia or otherwise), it's highly improbably that after N attempts none of the children are male. And being Phantom, he will have chances to try again and again and again. Presumably any woman he marries will know that he **has** to have a male heir and agree to that part of the deal beforehand - and the heir doesn't have to be born by someone he's monogamously married to.

Comment: Old jungle saying: "The Phantom doesn't fool around."

Comment: What makes you think female attraction in the jungles where he lives is hyperglamic in nature? Or were you saying all female attraction is hyperglamic (which is somewhat sexist)?

Comment: As for all daughters, it can happen. Families with only daughters are not uncommon. It seems the phantom would want to avoid that. Short of having multiple children with multiple partners and kidnapping a male, I can't see a sure way.

Comment: @Kristy - I wouldn't say **all**, but a vast majority are. It's a bit outside the scope to discuss this, but claiming that something backed up by basic game theory is "sexist" isn't really a very solid scientific argument. If you want a random practical example, look at % of women with college degree marrying men without one (or with lower grade one). Or just hung around any High School.

Comment: As far as all daughters - I'm not aware of specific gene that would lead a woman to ONLY have girls under normal circumstances, though I'm not an expert. Therefore, once you reach, say 16 kids (from 2 wives, just in case there IS such a gene I'm not aware of), the likelyhood of no boys is way too low to be interested in as far as a practical possibility. Any woman marrying a Phantom - just like one marrying a medieval King - would be fully aware that she is expected to have as many kids as possible to have a boy, and wouldn't agree to the marriage if she didn't agree to the concept.

Comment: @DVK It's not the mother who determines the gender of the child, it's the father - after all, (most) women don't have a Y chromosome, and so cannot provide one to their offspring. There's actually a rare mutation in men that leads to them only being able to have daughters, which is part of what skews natural gender ratios towards more women; thus, it is entirely plausible for a man to have 16 female children. Presumably the Phantom's power prevents his inheritor from having that mutation.

Comment: @KirstyMcNair I've taken this discussion to [skeptics.se](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8273/are-modern-women-predisposed-to-hypergamy), if you are interested.
DVK: I'm not sure anyone saying "just hang around any High School" as support for their claim about adult women in general should be throwing around the term "very solid scientific argument" ;)

Comment: @Beofett - Well, I could have said "around any politician" :)